# Finnicky #define behaviour in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, xinput

I've started to follow the [Handmade Hero series](https://handmadehero.org/). He's loading XInput manually, and has therefore created a function stub. It looks like this:

```
#define X_INPUT_GET_STATE(name) DWORD WINAPI name(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_STATE *pState)
typedef X_INPUT_GET_STATE(x_input_get_state);
X_INPUT_GET_STATE(XInputGetStateStub) {
    return 0;
}
global_variable x_input_get_state *XInputGetState_ = XInputGetStateStub;
#define XInputGetState XInputGetState_;
```

This is defined above any other functions. global_variable is a #define of static.

This code very nearly works. It compiles successfully if I use `if (XInputGetState_(ControllerIndex, &ControllerState) == ERROR_SUCCESS)` but doesn't compile when I use `if (XInputGetState(ControllerIndex, &ControllerState) == ERROR_SUCCESS)`

However, I can do as follows.

```
auto func = XInputGetState(ControllerIndex, &ControllerState);
if (func(ControllerIndex, &ControllerState) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

I'm utterly lost as to why this is happening.

**You can find the official function definition [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xinputgetstate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

**EDIT:**

Just to make matters more confusing. The XInputSetState function is also being defined manually.

```
#define X_INPUT_SET_STATE(name) DWORD WINAPI name(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_VIBRATION *pVibration)
typedef X_INPUT_SET_STATE(x_input_set_state);
X_INPUT_SET_STATE(XInputSetStateStub) {
    return 0;
}
global_variable x_input_set_state *XInputSetState_ = XInputSetStateStub;
#define XInputSetState XInputSetState_;
```

I can then call the function like this

```
XINPUT_VIBRATION Vibration;
Vibration.wLeftMotorSpeed = 60000;
Vibration.wRightMotorSpeed = 60000;
XInputSetState(0, Vibration);
```

This code runs and compiles without any problems;

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: That's why you should avoid `#define`, use the C++ language instead

Comment: I realize that there's probably better ways to do this, but I'm following the otherwise amazing series created by Casey Muratori.

Comment: You have an extra `;` in `#define XInputGetState XInputGetState_;`

Comment: @Jarod42 God freaking dammit. It really is this type of problem that keeps me up at night. How did I not see that?. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is one of the common errors with MACRO.

Comment: @Jarod42 I mostly program in C#, so there's some behaviour in c and c++ that seems very strange to me.

Comment: Macro are rarely the good solution. Works have been done to reduce their usage (inline methods, constant expressions, template, ...)